# Android studio - Possible to duplicate layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a contacts page. Each contact is contained within a RelativeLayout and has a few textviews and 10+ image views. Obviously there are going to be multiple contacts therefore layouts, is there any way to duplicate a generic layout rather than creating individual variables for each imageview and textview which would take forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use recyclerview or Listview .

**For recycler-view Have a look on   following link**

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

**For listview see this link**
 http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Thank you, I found using the recycler view as the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably looking for is a ListView.  The associated Adapter can construct a custom view from a common layout and used for each Contact.

Alternatively, there is the "include" layout tag which allows you to incorporate an external layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <include layout="@layout/separate_layout_file"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cursor adapter along with a listview.

1. Define a table in SQLite that will consist your contacts information.
2. Creating a view template for how one contact view should look like (seems like you already have that).
3. Define the cursor adapter and bind the data in your table to the view template/layout you created in step 2.
4. Retrieve the cursor which contains the information to your contacts table
5. Attach the adapter to a listview that will display all your contacts.

Check this [post](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter) out for a step by step tutorial if you need more information.